addEventListener beforeunload for prompt on leave doesn't work in React
I'm trying to setup a prompt on when the user is leaving the page, my simple code is:
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = "";
      alert("hello");
    });
  }, []);

Nothing is being triggered upon leaving / refreshing the page. Any idea why?
Tried on Chrome and Safari.

I have to correct: for some weird reason, it works sometimes only. About 20% of the time I try to reload, I see that popup window.

The documentation on MDN says:

Under some conditions — for example, when the user switches tabs — the browser may not actually display a dialog, or may not wait for the user to dismiss the dialog.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a more detailed explanation of these "conditions". But I assume this is to prevent e.g. non-active tabs to display alerts (or prompts or confirms), while the user views some other website.
I think the alert is displayed if the document has the focus (?). E.g. try click into the document somewhere, and if I'm right the alert should be displayed after that on reload or on leaving the page.
I know this is not really a solution. I assume this is a security mechanism, and can not be changed.
But probably there is no reason to display that alert, if the user never clicked on anything on the page. I don't know if there are other conditions where the alert would not be displayed.

I was experiencing something similar and found that the page needs some kind of interaction before the preventDefault() will work. Make sure you click somewhere on the page or within the app before leaving/refreshing the page.
Here is the documentation... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

To trigger the dialog being shown when the user closes or navigates
the tab, a beforeunload event handler function should call
preventDefault() on the event object. You should note that modern
implementations:

Require sticky activation for the dialog to be displayed. In other words, the browser will only show the dialog box if the frame or any embedded frame receives a user gesture or user interaction. If the user has never interacted with the page, then there is no user data to save, so no legitimate use case for the dialog.
Only show a generic browser-specified string in the displayed dialog. This cannot be controlled by the webpage code.


Also note: using an alert is not recommended within the beforeunload event.
